# Predicting duplicate questions quickly in production?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, duplicate-records

I found an interesting problem in Kaggle i.e. [Quora Question Pairs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/quora-question-pairs) in that we need to identify question pairs that have the same intent. According to their dataset, we have given a pair of questions and with target variable(whether they are duplicate or not) and in the dataset, we have 400,000 records. Let's imagine we have to build a good model and it's ready to predict. So at the time of prediction, we need to give a pair of questions to check whether they are similar/duplicate or not.

Now, let's say we need that model to find duplicate questions when the user tries to post any new question(similar to Stack Exchange websites or Quora website) so that he/she can know that this question have been already asked. But let say, in Quora, we have around 400,000 or many more questions and if we try to match every question to find the duplicate question then the system will take much longer time but I can see Stack Exchange and Quora handles it very quickly like within a second.

**How can we find duplicate questions from the list of 400,000 questions quickly?**

Comment: It would be quite ironic if this question was a duplicate on CrossValidated...
That being said, I think they might filter based on keywords so that you don't have to compare the question with every single question on the forum, but even if you had 400,000 questions, that could maybe be parallelized to not be too brutal using something like apache spark.

Comment: How to you define duplicates? If you mean exact duplicates, this is trivial, e.g. sort and compare adjacent pairs. You'll find more advanced solutions in every database software, numpy, pandas, or whatever you use.